# multiple template parameters in concept definition

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I have a concept with multiple template parameters

```
template<typename T, typename U> EqualityComparable
```

Can I use this in a

```
template< EqualityComparable T /* and U */ > void foo() {}
```

somehow?

As an example, consider this snippet

```
template <typename T, typename U>
concept EqualityComparable = requires(T a, U b) {
        {a == b} -> bool;
        {a != b} -> bool;
};

template<EqualityComparable T /* and U */>
void foo (T,U) {} //can i make this work?

int main () {
    foo(1.0f,1);
}
```

The clang experimental concepts compiler on godbolt tells me

```
template<EqualityComparable T /* and U */> void foo(T,U) {}

--> error: concept 'EqualityComparable' requires more than 1 template argument; provide the remaining arguments explicitly to use it here
```

so this seems to suggest it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
template<class T>
void foo_works(T, EqualityComparable<T> auto);
```

or equivalently:

```
template<class T, EqualityComparable<T> U>
void foo_works(T,U);
```

It will have the desired effect, but as it is written it does not reflect the symmetry of the EqualityComparable concept.

So some coder may prefer to use the non abbreviated syntax for constraints that are symmetrical:

```
template<class T,class U>
   requires EqualityComparable<T,U>
void foo_works(T,U);
```

With the concept TS there is this possibility:

```
EqualityComparable{T,U}
void foo_works(T,U);
```

But this syntax has scared conservatives.

Answer (score 2):

This is a possibility

```
template<typename A, typename B> requires EqualityComparable<T,U>
void foo_works(T,U) {}
```

but i wonder whether it works directly in the `template<>`

Comment: I've only skimmed concepts but I think that's the only way.

Comment: Herb Sutter's proposal for template parameter intoducers would solve this problem, but it would require more iterations before being merged in the language